# Antd Custom Theme in ReactJS without using .less

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd

I want to use Antd without importing the `less` in my ReactJS application. The major reason for that is that I am using the `create-react-app` boilerplate to create my application. Antd requires me to modify webpack.config.js to compile the less for deploying my code on any server. I don't want to bad code by modifying the webpack inside the `node_modules` and I don't have enough knowledge to use npm eject. Can anyone suggest to me a solution to use `Antd` with `create-react-app`?

Comment: You can just import `antd/dist/antd.css`

Comment: @YashJoshi I am doing that. I want to customize the theme colors

Comment: ant uses less variables to customize the theme, so you need to config less if you want to have custom colors. or get the css file and change the colors locally.

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani I agree. I have read the docs. I just want a way to integrate and with create-react-app without doing npm eject or modifying node modules

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with create-react-app without doing npm eject or modifying node modules. Below are some packages that you needed:

- [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired): tweak the create-react-app webpack config(s) without using 'eject' and without creating a fork of the react-scripts.
- [customize-cra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/customize-cra): we need customize-cra along with react-app-rewired due to new [react-app-rewired@2.x](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#alternatives) issue.
- [babel-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import): for importing components on demand.
- [less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less): default development language for styling in antd.
- [less-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-loader): compiler for translating less into css.

if you just want to change the color one time, here is a good article:

- [[3 Steps] Customize theme for Ant Design with create-react-app 2019](http://www.edwardhk.com/language/js/3-steps-customize-theme-for-ant-design-with-create-react-app-2019/)

If you want to change it on runtime you need another package:

- [antd-theme-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-generator) or [antd-theme-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-webpack-plugin)

A good article of using antd-theme-generator:

- [Change-Ant-Design-Theme-dynamically-in-React-Create-React-App](https://annacoding.com/article/gVcF6qCZkfnM3JOnPxBqx/Change-Ant-Design-Theme-dynamically-in-React-Create-React-App)

I've made an article on using antd-theme-webpack-plugin:

- [5 steps to change antd theme on runtime using create-react-app](https://dev.to/christianandrei/5-steps-to-change-antd-theme-on-runtime-using-create-react-app-p2k)